# Create an option pane without buttons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

In Swing how can I create an option dialog box that doesn't have any buttons or the icon at the top?

I want to use `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`, but there are always buttons at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the icon, set the message type to JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE.

To create a dialog box without buttons you do 2 things.

1. Set the option type to JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
2. Set the options array to an empty array:  `new Object[] {}`

The final code looks like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();  // Create and modify this panel
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, 
                             panel, 
                             "Dialog Title", 
                             JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, // NO Icon
                             null, 
                             new Object[] {},  // No options
                             null);
```

Comment: Instead of -1, maybe `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`.